# Allow line break in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page where I use

```
<c:out value="${var}" />
```

to display the variable for protection against XSS, but I want only some `<BR>` to be allowed. How is it possible?

I also want line breaks (`\n`) to get converted to `<BR>`.

Comment: not possible. I wrote my own function for that purpose. Look how `c:out` implemented und make your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach, for example:

```
<c:set var="newLine" value='\\n' />
<c:set var="br" value='<br />' />

<c:out value="${fn:replace(sometext, newLine, br)}" escapeXml="false"/>
```